# Why is my virtual machine inaccessible?

Tags: virtualbox, log

I want to start my virtual machine but in `VirtualBox Manager`, it says it's **inaccessible** and that I should be inspecting the error log which says:

```
Document is empty.
Location: '/home/ron/VirtualBox VMs/Semios Win7 /Semios Win7 .vbox', line 1 (0), column 1.
/home/vbox/vbox-5.0.12/src/VBox/Main/src-server/MachineImpl.cpp[740] (nsresult Machine::i_registeredInit()).
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
```

The only problem is, I don't know how to interpret what I'm seeing. What does all this mean?

Comment: Are you sure about the trailing space in the name? What does `VBoxManage list vms` say?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Go to the location where you store your VM `/home/ron/VirtualBox VMs/Semios Win7 /`.

Open `.vbox` in your favorite text editor to check if it is empty. Probably it is :) In the same folder you should have file `Semios Win7 .vbox-prev`. Copy the contents of this file to `Semios Win7.vbox`, save, and try again.

Now it should work. I did the same and it worked for me.

Comment: what to do if its in ubuntu?

Comment: @kashminder Do the same thing. Just check what is your main folder for storing virtual machines data. 

If you don't know it do this in Virtual Box GUI: New > check "use existing virtual hard disk file" > click the folder icon > tadam, this is your root folder.

Comment: its the same still. working for the root user but not with logged in one.

Comment: @kashminder Check your permissions than. ls -l your vm folder. Add user to sudo or change permissions for vm files.

Comment: That solved it for me, thank you so much! But what might have caused the file to go to 0kb?

Comment: @user240891 In my case i ran out of space on disk and had to reboot. After reboot that file was 0kb.

Comment: seems to have been the same reason for me too, thank you!

Comment: Works! Date: 14/06/2018 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS! Thanks!